# maximum collector-emitter voltage in BJTs

Tags: bjt, bias, base

I am reading [BC817 datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BC817-25QA_40QA.pdf). According to the datasheet, maximum collector-emitter voltage at open base condition is 45 V. In typical applications we don't use open base configuration. My question is that how can I find maximum collector-emitter voltage when the base is biased. I could not find relevant information in the datasheet (Maybe I have not enough knowledge about it). Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Simply do not exceed 45V and you will be fine. Form what I remember Vceo is the smallest breakdown voltage.

Answer (score 1):

when you are biased the transistor may be particaly open
you can calculate depends on the biasing the Vce voltage using simple DC analysis:
first you need to know the base current can be calculated by KCL
then collector current can be calculated by Ic=hfe*Ib
and the emmiter current is Ie=Ic+Ib
so now just substruct the main brunch voltages to get Vce

here is a great example for DC analysis
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/biasing-calculations/

Answer (score 0):

Beware of charge transfer from collector to base, during fast edges; the moving charge may overpower whatever sets the base voltage, and take the base voltage POSITIVE and thus turn on the transistor.